# Wrong Laravel validation messasges

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I get the wrong error messages. My purpose is following : 
1. checking username / pw combination, and if it doesn't match, "wrong username/pw combination" error through validator.
2. captcha (mews) is troubling me. Even user enters true captcha chars (no case-sensitive by config) I get the error message.
Here is my validator :
*FYI: i have a table "user" instead of users, and i can use it nicely in other controllers.*

```
protected function loginValidator()
{
    $message = array(
        'exists:user,username' => 'Wrong username/pass combination',
        'exists' => 'Wrong :attribute.',
        'required' => ':attribute cannot be empty',
        'captcha' => 'Wrong captcha'
    );

    return Validator::make(Input::all(),[
        'usernameInput' => 'required|exists:user,username',
        'passwordInput' => 'required',
        'captchaInput' => 'captcha|required'
    ], $message);
}
```

Even if username/pass combination is true, i get wrong captcha message.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function loginValidator()
{
  $validator = Validator::make(
    array(
      'name' => 'Dayle',
      'password' => 'lamepassword',
      'email' => 'email@example.com'
    ),
    array(
      'name' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required|min:8',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
    )
  );

  if ($validator->fails())
  {
    // The given data did not pass validation
    $data['messages'] = $validator->messages()->all();
  }
  else
  {
    //complete validation
  }

  return View::make('home.login', $data);
}
```

Comment: SO encourages you to explain the code or at least somehow relate it to the question, e.g. using the comment outside the code block, etc...

Comment: thank you both. I will feedback when i am able to test.